# Why does `git stripspace` delete all text?

Tags: git, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to run `git stripspace` but the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace) is not helpfull.

It *appears* that `git stripspaces` takes `stdin` as its input and writes to `stdout` but:

```
% git stripspace < myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

deleted all the text in `myfile.txt`

I wish the documentation provided an invocation example. Does anyone have one?

Comment: The problem with your command is not that stripspace is poorly documented, it is because you're redirecting the output to the same file you're reading from. This doesn't work for any command. Try redirecting to a different file.

Comment: Didn't `git stripspace myfile.txt` work?

Comment: It wasn't git that did it. When you redirect stdout to a file, it first creates that file. Which in your case, created it empty (in other words, it overwrote your file).

Comment: Aha. Thanks!  I didn't realize that.

Comment: I do agree that the documentation could be made slightly clearer by also saying what it did with the cleaned text, and also by providing an actual example of execution, but I don't necessarily agree that it was *worthless*.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, while *worthless* may be a bit harsh, it must be said that I could not read the documentation and, from that information, run the command.  That is most of the worth of a piece of documentation.

Comment: @RomainVALERI on my version it brings up the usage information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're redirecting **from** and **to** the same file. It wasn't GIT that did it. When you redirect stdout to a file, it first creates that file. Which in your case, created it empty (in other words, it overwrote your file).

Try changing your simple command, which is this:

```
git stripspace < myfile.txt > myfile.txt
```

to this:

```
git stripspace < myfile.txt > my-other-file.txt
```

and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`sponge` is the tool to solve exactly this problem.  It first "soaks up" all of the data piped into it then writes it out to the specified file.  It's part of the `moreutils` package - on Ubuntu install it with `sudo apt install moreutils`,

Here's an example using a file `spacetest.txt` - the `awk` command is used to to help visualize the trailing spaces that exist in the file:

```
# print the file spacetest.txt with '%' appended to each line-end to show trailing spaces

~/temp/stripspace-test$ awk '{ print $0 "%" }' spacetest.txt 
%
%
line 1 has a space at the end %
line 2 has 2 spaces at the end  %
line 3 has 3 spaces at the end   %
%
the next line has 4 spaces%
    %
three blank lines follow this one%
%
%
%

# 'redirect' from and to spacetest.txt using `sponge` as a go-between

~/temp/stripspace-test$ git stripspace < spacetest.txt | sponge  spacetest.txt


# print the file spacetest.txt again to demonstrate everything is as expected

~/temp/stripspace-test$ awk '{ print $0 "%" }' spacetest.txt 
line 1 has a space at the end%
line 2 has 2 spaces at the end%
line 3 has 3 spaces at the end%
%
the next line has 4 spaces%
%
three blank lines follow this one%
```